# BeanCreationException: Component declared but not exist in registry

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I started learning camel recently and trying out some sample application. I have encountered this error while loading application context as part of testcase run,

> ... 45 more Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:
>   Failed to create route route2 at: >>>
>   Bean[ref:orderItemMessageTranslator method: transformOrderItemMessage]
>   <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[sql:select id from orders."order"
>   where ... because of No bean could be found in the registry for:
>   orderItemMessageTranslator    at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:910)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:780)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2068)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1816)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.afterPropertiesSet(SpringCamelContext.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 60 more Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean
>   could be found in the registry for: orderItemMessageTranslator    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.getBean(RegistryBean.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.createProcessor(BeanDefinition.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:499)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:907)
>     ... 71 more

Tried my best by googling and looking at stack overflow to resolve but my effort went in vain. Need some help.

Here is my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxMMD.png)

Below are some related files used w.r.t to my sample application for your reference,

```
Application.java:
---------------------
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pluralsight.orderfulfillment")
@PropertySource("classpath:order-fulfillment.properties")
public class Application {

}

IntegrationConfig.java:
-------------------------
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Inject
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Bean
    public SqlComponent sql() {
        SqlComponent sqlComponent = new SqlComponent();
        sqlComponent.setDataSource(datasource);
        return sqlComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder newWebsiteOrderRoute() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("sql:"
                    + "select id from orders.\"order\" where status = '"
                    + OrderStatus.NEW.getCode()
                    + "'"
                    + "?"
                    + "consumer.onConsume=update orders.\"order\" set status = '"
                    + OrderStatus.PROCESSING.getCode()
                    + "' where id=:#id")
                .beanRef("orderItemMessageTranslator", "transformOrderItemMessage")
                .to("log:com.pluralsight.orderfulfillment.order?level=INFO");

            }

        };
    }
}

Pom.xml:
---------
..
..
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK -->

        <!-- Spring framework core dependency minus commons logging in favor of SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>       
..
..
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you decorated the `OrderItemMessageTranslator` with the `@Component` annotation?

Instead of `.beanRef(..)`, try the `.bean(..)` builder method from the Java DSL(http://camel.apache.org/bean.html#Bean-JavaDSLbeansyntax):

```
.bean(new OrderItemMessageTranslator(), "transformOrderItemMessage")
```

**UPDATE:**

If you would like to use the `.beanRef(..)` method then try to add `@ComponentScan(..)` to the `IntegrationConfig` which extends `CamelConfiguration`.

Like this: http://camel.apache.org/spring-java-config.html#SpringJavaConfig-Configuration

Comment: yes, @component annotation is there..bean() builder worked and it resolved my issue. Just curious to know why beanRef() is not working in my case..

Comment: Try to add `@ComponentScan` to the CamelConfiguration class (as you can see in my updated answer).